# React - Media Query CSS style is always selected

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

I am building a small React application and want to hide some elements when the width of the screen is less than 576px. The issue I run into is that the media query CSS style is applied regardless of the width as if it would not pick up the width at all.

Index.html is set to:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1″>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code looks like this:

```
.headingList {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.listItem {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Brand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    color: white;
}

.listItem:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.listItem:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.listItemBurger {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 577px) {
    .headingList {
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .listItem {
        display: none;
    }
    .listItemBurger {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

**Edit** Added the HTML code:

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./NavigationBox.css";
import Burgermenu from "../BurgerMenu/BurgermenuIcon.js"
const navBarContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.navBar}>
            <ul className={classes.headingList}>
                <li className={classes.Brand}>Shop Advisor</li>
                <li className={classes.listItem}>FAQ</li>
                <li className={classes.listItem}>Pricing</li>
                <li className={classes.listItem}>About Us</li>
                <li className={classes.listItemBurger} onClick={props.burgerMenuExpand}><Burgermenu/></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    );
    };
export default navBarContainer;
```

Also attached the processed html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0022)http://localhost:3000/ -->
<html lang="en" class="gr__localhost"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="”viewport”" content="”width=device-width," initial-scale="1″">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./React App_files/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./React App_files/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="http://localhost:3000/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <style type="text/css">body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style><style type="text/css">.App__App__3Ge-C {
  text-align: center;
}

.App__App-logo__S1Lue {
  -webkit-animation: App__App-logo-spin__2zbnz infinite 20s linear;
          animation: App__App-logo-spin__2zbnz infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App__App-header__1mzDF {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App__App-title__tAcLI {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App__App-intro__2BdAl {
  font-size: large;
}

@-webkit-keyframes App__App-logo-spin__2zbnz {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes App__App-logo-spin__2zbnz {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style><style type="text/css">.TopNavigationsBar__navBar__3rdGx {
    height:28px;
    background-color: #144269;
}</style><style type="text/css">.NavigationBox__headingList__3Cw-y {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.NavigationBox__Brand__1n3_W {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    color: white;
}

.NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
            transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
}

.NavigationBox__listItemBurger__34lVD {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 577px) {
    .NavigationBox__headingList__3Cw-y {
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR {
        display: none;
    }
    .NavigationBox__listItemBurger__34lVD {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}</style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css">.BurgerMenuLinks__expanded__3lWG1 {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #144269;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 28px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

.BurgerMenuLinks__notexpanded__3l7KI {
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #144269;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 28px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}</style></head>
  <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" class="vsc-initialized" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"><div class="App"><div class="TopNavigationsBar__navBar__3rdGx"><div><ul class="NavigationBox__headingList__3Cw-y"><li class="NavigationBox__Brand__1n3_W">Shop Advisor</li><li class="NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR">FAQ</li><li class="NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR">Pricing</li><li class="NavigationBox__listItem__1wNPR">About Us</li><li class="NavigationBox__listItemBurger__34lVD"><div><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div></li></ul></div><div class="BurgerMenuLinks__notexpanded__3l7KI"></div></div></div></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./React App_files/bundle.js.download"></script>

</body></html>
```

Would anyone have an idea how to solve this?

I appreciate your help on it!

Comment: Where's your HTML code?

Comment: Just added the HTML code onto which the CSS styling is applied to.

Comment: Thanks but I think it would be much more helpful to debug this issue if we have the final HTML output and not just the non-processed JSX HTML.

Comment: Added the processed HTML output as well (formatting is not ideal though)

Comment: inspect the element and check whether the css is applied. If it's applied and overrided just add `!important` to the css

Comment: On inspect element, I can see that the media-query piece is present, but it does not apply the style once it hits a width of 577px if I use !important on the 'regular' css style

Comment: I just tested it on another browser - it works fine in IE 11 but not in Chrome. Does anybody have an idea what the reason could be?